# PHPunit, Getting function code coverage for a ZF controller action

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, code-coverage, zend-test

I'm using PHPunit to test our Zend Framework project and it works allright but i'm not getting coverage om my action methods in my controllers.

Although I get coverage in number off lines of code but I want to have coverage on the functions/methods.

I see a lot of examples on the internet where they just do it like this:

```
class IndexTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
  public function testIndexAction() {
    $this->dispatch('/');
    $this->assertController('index');
    $this->assertAction('index');
    $this->assertXpath("//form[@action = '/index']");
  }
}
```

Which should work even if I look to this example from Jon:

http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-with-the-zend-framework-with-zend_test-and-phpunit/2009/06/

http://code.google.com/p/zendcasts/source/browse/#svn/trunk/zc25-unit-testing

I'm doing it almost the exact way but it's not giving me any percentage of code coverage in functions, except for the init() function but I think that one is automaticly ignored by Zend Controller testcase.

I'm I doing something stupid or doesn't PHPUnit reconize it's calling this action? Using PHPUnit 3.5.14 and Zend Framework 1.11.x

Comment: Are you sure your function is actually getting called?

Comment: No that's the point, code coverage is saying indexAction is not called and therefor not covered but I can't find out why it says it's not called while other lines of code _inside_ that function are covered?

Comment: What version of Xdebug are you running?

Comment: According to my phpinfo i'm running xdebug 2.1.0

Comment: I figured out, it's a stupid mistake, because you need to cover all lines of a specific function in order to get 100% coverage for that method. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get code coverage for a specific function from PHPunit you need to make sure every line of your function is called by your tests, so that every possible situation is taken care of and tested.